# How to restrict duplicate entry in custom directive Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Below is my custom directive and it will appear when our view will render.

```
  (function() {
    'use strict';

    function autoComplete(Configuration) {
            //link function will execute when this directive will render with view.
      function linkFn(scope, element) {
        //in scope.data I will get all my data from the controller but need to parse only unique data here
        //in scope.data I want only unique entries
        console.log(scope.data);
        var config = {
          source: function(request, response) {
            var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(scope.data || [], request.term);
            response(results.slice(0, Configuration.MAX_AUTOCOMPLETE_RESULT));
          }
        };
        //all set let's initialise the auto complete of jquery.
        element.autocomplete(config);
      }

      //our directive definition object.
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        // Isolated scope for our directive.
        scope: {
          data: '='
        },
        link: linkFn
      };
    }

    var app = angular.module('app'),
      requires = [
        'Configuration',
        autoComplete
      ];
    app.directive('autoComplete', requires);
  }());
```

Here is directive I will get data from the controller and I want to parse unique data from scope.data.

Comment: You haven't provided any sample data.

Comment: Sample data will come dynamically .
For reference point  you can take example ["abc","xyz","abc","pqr"] 
@ sisyphus

Comment: I found the following to remove duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array/9229821#9229821

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but duplicates in a javascript array can be removed using Array.filter.

```
var arr =  ["abc","xyz","abc","pqr"]
console.log('duplicate array : ' + arr)

var unique_arr = arr.filter(function(element, index, array) {
    return index == array.indexOf(element);
})

console.log('unique arr ' + unique_arr);
```

For further reading, check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thank you for your Answer.But I am looking into a filter which can remove all the duplicate from directive scope.data[].

Comment: Again, I don't understand. How is removing duplicates from scope.data[] within a directive different from any regular javascript code? Just replaca `var arr` to `scope.data`